# JQuery to set the height of a div on page load

Tags: jquery, html, height

OK so I have a container div that loads some content which is generated by php. I don't know what the height of the content is and it is absolute positioned so the container div doesn't know how high to be until all the content is there. I collect the the height it needs to be in a php variable and want to use jquery to set the container div to this height but it's not working yet.

I have put this code near the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#DynContainer").css({height:<?php echo $containerHeight; ?>px})
});
</script>
```

It is currently not working but looking at the code the php variable is echoed into it correctly. E.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#DynContainer").css({height:440px})
});
</script>
```

EDIT:

As many have helpfully suggested I needed to provide valid code for the CSS. I have since changed it to generate this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var containerHeight = "440px";
$("#DynContainer").css({height: containerHeight})
});
```

However it still doesn't work. The ID reference is deffo correct.

EDIT2:

Looking at the console I get this error:

```
[15:46:29.460] TypeError: $ is not a function @ http://localhost/serge/?page_id=2045:242
```

Suggesting jQuery is not loaded, but it's definitely called at the top of the page. Here is the whole page code: http://pastebin.com/tGadjaRA

SOLVED: it was a noconflict jQuery issue.
Thanks everyone

Comment: Hm is #DynContainer spelled correctly? Check for case.

Comment: you need to put 440px into a string ("440px") as that is what it is: {height:"440px"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put quotes around the value, since it's a string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#DynContainer").css({height:'<?php echo $containerHeight; ?>px'})
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/GF3EK/

Alternatively, remove the "px" and the quotes so it's parsed as an integer ("px" is the default unit):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#DynContainer").css({height:<?php echo $containerHeight; ?>})
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/GF3EK/1/

Answer (score 0):

The "px" is resulting in invalid javascript.  As other answers suggest, you can put quotes around it or you can remove the px completely:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DynContainer").css({height:<?php echo $containerHeight; ?>})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend passing PHP variables to JS at the beginning of the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var containerHeight = <?php echo $containerHeight; ?>;
// from now, it's pure JS. both better maintainable and readable
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DynContainer").css({'height': containerHeight})
});
</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks all but I'm still having trouble. I have changed the code and looking at the page source the javascript generated is:    `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
 var containerHeight = "440px";
 $("#DynContainer").css({height: containerHeight})
});
</script>`

Comment: It works for me, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/2MuD3/2/ Do you have correct ID corresponding to the DynContainer element?

Comment: I know this is extremely late but if you tried to mess with the style it might work better. $("element").attr("style", "height:" + containerHeight); I know you probably already solved this problem though